# Delete a specific key value using the defaults delete command line tool

Tags: plist, defaults

Having the following .plist file:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist

{
    DisabledPreferencePanes =     (
        "com.apple.preference.general",
        "com.apple.preference.mouse"
    );
}
```

Using the `defaults` command line tool, if I want to `delete` for example only the **com.apple.preference.mouse** line from the plist how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *output* of the `defaults` *command*, in your OP, shows a single *key*, **DisabledPreferencePanes**, as an *array* with two *elements*. Unfortunately `defaults` cannot explicitly delete a single *element* in an *array* containing multiple *elements*, in this case **com.apple.preference.mouse**.

Since the target **com.apple.systempreferences.plist** *file* in **/Library/Preferences** only has the single *key* as an *array*, the entire *file* and thus the *array* can be overwritten without the target *element* in the *array*, e.g.:

**NOTE:** This form of the *command* **overwrites the entire target *file***.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist '{ DisabledPreferencePanes = ("com.apple.preference.general"); }'
```

If the target **.plist** *file* had other *keys*, you could **overwrite** just the target *key*, e.g:

**NOTE:** This form of the *command* **overwrites just the target *array***.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist DisabledPreferencePanes -array com.apple.preference.general
```

That said, I prefer to use **PlistBuddy** because a single *element* of the *array* can be deleted, e.g.:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :DisabledPreferencePanes:1" /Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist
```

- In **PlistBuddy**, *array* items are specified by a zero-based integer index.

**PlistBuddy** can also be easier to use in a *shell script* where one could *code* it to find a target *element* of an *array* and delete it. This could not be done with `defaults` as it can only write (or overwrite) an *array* without the target *element* in it.

---

**Notes:**

- **System Preferences** should be closed when modifying its releated **.plist** *files*.
- Immediately after modifying the target *file*, in this use case, you need to terminate all occurrences of **cfprefsd**.

  - As one is owned by **root** you'll need to use **sudo** in **Terminal**, e.g.:

    ```
    sudo killall cfprefsd
    ```
  - If you do not do this, the edited *file* may/will be overwriten by its *original copy* in *memory*, thus making the changes null and void.
- **cfprefsd** will reload on its own afterwards.